# Opensource project using apache derby

Tags: derby

Does anybody know of a few open source projects that are using apache derby?

*Background:*

I need to analyze the parse trees of some sql statements, and have derby's sql parser isolated for the purpose. Now what I need is bunch of sql statements for testing and a real life open source project using derby would be a perfect for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Projects & Products using/supporting Derby](http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UsesOfDerby)

Answer (score 0):

Splice Machine is an open source project that is a fork of Apache Derby.

You can check it out here...

https://github.com/splicemachine/spliceengine

We have implemented

explain -> any sql statement

so you can see Derby's explain plan.  We also have written an AST visualizer if you need additional help.  I can provide a link to that if needed.